# Spacing problem after a list at the beginning of a theorem

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems

In the following example, how (if possible) can one make the line after the fruits be formatted in the same way as the line after the vegetables in a "clean" way without moving the `apple` to a new line?  Here, by a "clean" way, I mean not having to specify the spacing explicitly (in the text or buried in a new macro).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item apple
\item orange
\end{enumerate}
This is indented like a paragraph with no extra vertical spacing before it.
\end{thm}

\begin{enumerate}
\item lettuce
\item cabbage
\end{enumerate}
This is how I want it.
\end{document}
```

Comment: List environments “remember” how they were called; since no vertical space precedes the list in the theorem, none follows it. In my opinion, theorem statements should never start with an enumerate, but I know this doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the explanation.  Although this doesn't solve the issue, it is always good to know what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

if you *must* start a theorem with a run-in enumerated list, you can enter the first line manually, then begin the `enumerate` on the next line starting with "2":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
1. apple
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
%\item apple
\item orange
\end{enumerate}
This is how I want it.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

if the first item is more than one line long, or in an italic theorem statement where the document class sets the item numbers upright, a more
elaborate approach is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  Your answer does meet my "clean" criterion as stated above, but I have to admit that I really cannot make myself say this is clean.  Sorry, perhaps I should not attempt to define what "clean" means.

Comment: there's no question -- this is *ugly*!  and if you want to label the items, it doesn't permit labeling the first one.  but there's another problem with starting a theorem with `enumerate` and that is, the space between the theorem header and the item number on the same line is usually too wide.  a "fix" would involve changing how lists work, and that is in the core design of latex.  (i haven't looked at the packages `enumitem` or `enumerate` to see if they do anything different.)